# How can I use an array as a jquery plugin parameter?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to pass an array as an option (op3 : array1) of a plugin I'm creating:

```
var array1 = new Array();
$('.myGrid').myGrid({
  op1: 1,
  op2: 'value',
  op3: array1
});
```

Plugin code:

```
var defaults = {  
  op1: 1,
  op2: 'value',
  op3: array1
};

var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

var arr = new Array();
arr[0] = 0;
arr[1] = 1;
options.op3 = arr;
```

I'm I doing it right? I want to update *array1* everytime I do something like:

```
options.op3 = arr;
```

And being able to use/alert *array1* values on other javascript code of the page.

Thank you!

Comment: When you use the `var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);`, the `defaults` will be overwritten by what is in `options`. I am not sure what you are using `var arr = new Array();
arr[0] = 0;
arr[1] = 1;
options.op3 = arr;` for. If `options.op3 = arr;` is attempting to update `op3`, it was already done when it was passed via the `$.extend({}, defaults, options)` statement.

Comment: My plugin will process many things. After it's process is done, I want `array1` to have all the data that was updated.

Comment: I would suggest using a `console.log()` to display your option to see if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: I just want to pass any variable value to the plugin.